Buffer without overlaps in Python
I have a set of points with respective lat/long coordinates and each point has a given value associated with it (basically a field measurement). I would like to draw buffers of a given radius around those points. The geometries of the output buffers will overlap significantly and I would like for the output geometries to not overlap. Basically, something similar to what Buffer without overlay is showing. However, I have some constraints regarding the tools that can be used and the output:

Must be achieved using Python.
Should use tools that do not have dependencies on gdal. This is because I am struggling to install the library and I have not figured out a way to make it work on my computer despite checking multiple posts and videos online. A solution using packages like geopandas and shapely would be great.
The output geometries of the buffers should retain the original value associated with the point. For example, a dissolve operation could be performed but the original attributes are lost.

I have found this post useful where the package momepy may be a suitable solution. I have tried it with some sample data (500 points). You can access the csv in this link. I have tried the following code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import momepy
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

# load the csv file and convert to GeoDataFrame
gdf = pd.read_csv("points_demo.csv")
geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(gdf["Longitude"], gdf["Latitude"])
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gdf, geometry=geometry, crs="EPSG:4326")

# change to projected CRS
gdf = gdf.to_crs(7856)

# create unique ID for points
gdf["point_id"] = np.arange(1, gdf.shape[0] + 1)

# specify buffer in meters
buffer = 10

# create a limit for tessellation (join all polygons and buffer that)
limit = gdf.unary_union.buffer(buffer)

# create tessellation
tess = momepy.Tessellation(gdf, unique_id="point_id", limit=limit, segment=10, shrink=10)

# get the resulting GeoDataFrame
result = tess.tessellation


Unfortunately the above does not work. Any other ideas using different packages (again with the exception of packages with dependencies on GDAL) are welcomed.

Starting from your code, I think voronoi polygons can simply replace the use of Tesselation from momepy because you are using points as input.
Since the recently released geopandas 1.0 direct support to create voronoi polygons has been added to geopandas: geopandas.voronoi_polygons. Mind though: the voronoi polygons returned are not in the same order of the input points, so the point attributes need to be spatially joined to them if they need to be retained as is the case here.
Finally, the voronoi polygons can be clipped using the buffered points to get the result.
Sample script:
from pathlib import Path
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

# load the csv file and convert to GeoDataFrame
points_path = Path(__file__).parent / "2024-07-11_buffer_no_overlaps_points_demo.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(points_path)
geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(df["Longitude"], df["Latitude"])
points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geometry, crs="EPSG:4326")

# change to projected CRS
points = points.to_crs("EPSG:7856")

# create unique ID for points
points["point_id"] = np.arange(1, points.shape[0] + 1)

# create voronoi polygons
voronois = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=points.voronoi_polygons(), crs=points.crs)
# The order of the voronoi polygons is not guaranteed, so sjoin the attributes of the
# points. Recover the index of the original points.
voronois = voronois.sjoin(points, predicate="intersects").set_index("index_right")
assert len(voronois) == len(points)

# specify buffer in meters
buffer = 10

# create a limit for voronois (union all points and buffer them)
limit = points.union_all().buffer(buffer)

# clip the voronois to the limit
result = voronois.clip(limit)
print(result)

# plot
ax = result.plot()
points.plot(ax=ax, color="red")
plt.show()

Result:


Did not know about that functionality in geopandas. Thank you very much.

Sounds like you want to be using a Euclidian allocation approach. Your question is about using python and avoiding GDAL. My solution which is neither of your two constraints is simply 1 tool in ArcGIS Pro. I used the Distance Allocation tool to achieve below. So a single tool. It's output is raster but than can be easily converted to vector.
So I suggest you explore your alternate libraries and search for something like "Euclidian allocation" to see if they have such a function?
If what you are doing is a one time run of your data, if there is no equivalence in the code libraries you want to use, then this may be an approach for a GIS person to do it.


Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I needed this on a pipeline that needs to be run multiple times programmatically.
